# how to make diagonal div

Tags: css, html

[image]

This is my `div` tag where I want to write hello on red area. How do I write it into that? Please help!

```css
.arrow-right {
  height: 100px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
  border-top: 170px solid red;
  border-right: 170px solid orange;
  width: 200px;
  padding-top: -190px;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow-right">Hello</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. So you should check out how to ask a good question: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. It's very unclear to me what it is that you expect? where to you want the diagonal div? What does the placement of "Hello" have to do with this? these would be good questions to answer.

Comment: @Saba: Did my answer solve your solution, or are you still looking?

Answer (score 4):

I've used positioning and a pseudo element to achieve this:

```css
.arrow-right {
  height: 100px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
  border-top: 170px solid red;
  border-right: 170px solid orange;
  width: 200px;
position:relative;
}
.arrow-right:before{
  content:"hello";
  position:absolute;
  top:-170px;
  font-size:50px
  }
```

```html
<div class="arrow-right"></div>
```

---

So, if you only wanted the 'red' part, you would end up with something similar to this:

```css
.arrow-right {
  height: 1px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-top: 170px solid red;
  border-right: 170px solid transparent;
  width: 200px;
position:relative;
}
.arrow-right:before{
  content:"hello";
  position:absolute;
  top:-170px;
  font-size:50px
  }
```

```html
<div class="arrow-right"></div>
```

Comment: Great answer. Do you understand what is "diagonal" here? lol.

Comment: i would *guess* that OP is eventually looking to just have the 'red' part of the div. But at present, I understand your puzzlement between the question's title and its content.